# Why converting '1' char to int using toInt method results to 49?

Tags: scala

I want to convert a char to an int value.
I am a bit puzzled by the way `toInt` works.

```scala
println(("123").toList)         //List(1, 2, 3)
("123").toList.head             // res0: Char = 1
("123").toList.head.toInt       // res1: Int = 49 WTF??????
```

49 pops up randomly for no reason.
How do you convert a char to int the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Integer.parseInt("1", 10). Note that the 10 here is the radix.

```
val x = "1234"
val y = x.slice(0,1)
val z = Integer.parseInt(y)
val z2 = y.toInt //equivalent to the line above, see @Rogach answer
val z3 = Integer.parseInt(y, 8) //This would give you the representation in base 8 (radix of 8)
```

49 does not pop up randomly. It's the ascii representation of "1". See http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: This worked. Additionally I had to use `(someCharValue).toString` convert a char to a string. I'll accept in 5 min.

Comment: Integer.parseInt takes a string yes. If you want the first char only, use "1234".substring(0,1) or "1234".slice(0,1). This returns a string.

Please, make sure not to use what Kim Stebel suggested ( c match { ... } ). This is very bad practice.

Answer (score 5):

For simple digit to int conversions there is `asDigit`:

```
scala> "123" map (_.asDigit)
res5: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.toInt` will give you the ascii value. It's probably easiest to write

```
"123".head - '0'
```

If you want to handle non-numeric characters, you can do

```
c match {
  case c if '0' <= c && c <= '9' => Some(c - '0')
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: I advise against using the code above (c match { ... }) for this situation . It's very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
"123".head.toString.toInt
```